# Xerces-C "The primary document entity could not be opened"

Tags: xml, xsd, xerces

I've got an error message coming in that I've not seen before in my XML processing code.  I've not really changed anything recently, but we're moving stuff around here at the moment.  The programs I've run so far are all affected.

```
Warning at file , line=0, column=0, An exception occurred! Type:RuntimeException, Message:Warning: The primary document entity could not be opened. Id=/tmp/authNotify.xsd
```

Notice there is no file name listed ("Warning at file ,").  I don't have any XSD files in the /tmp directory at all, so it shouldn't be looking there.  Puzzled!

The XML files are the same as always.  I can post whatever you all might think is helpful.  The current directory is not /tmp.

I'm using Xerces-C 2.8 on an AS/400 environment here.

Comment: Could you post an example of a XML file you're trying to parse? It could be trying to open a XSD file that doesn't actually exist (maybe take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESC-544)

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to occur when xercesc opens an xml file to read it successfully, then when it's open the file below the filehandle is deleted, leaving the filehandle open but pointing to nothing. To reproduce create and delete the xml file in a tight loop, and after some time xercesc will generate this error.